# Android Locale display plugin

Tags: android, plugins

Hi is it possible to use the plugins present in this link http://www.twofortyfouram.com/developer  to detect the display of the device.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if device is on/off with that and use that with some apps that are supporting Locale plugins. If you need to implement same in your app, just check how that is implemented.